# Multi language not applied to main form

Tags: c#

I use this code for multi language

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
{
    ComponentResourceManager res = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
    res.ApplyResources(item, item.Name, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

It work's with all forms, but it doesn't work with main form.

Comment: `it work with all forms but it doesn't work with main form`, please show the code on the main form ... If it's not done on the new constructor, then it won't work. Also you should be able to do this before your application starts.

Comment: This may help: [Changing Your Application User Interface Culture On The Fly](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23694/Changing-Your-Application-User-Interface-Culture-O)